# Django handling Foreign Keys of tables in VIEWS in postgres; QuerySet always empty

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-queryset

Is Django or maybe POSTGRESQL losing information about primary keys and foreign keys when you create a view which relates to a view which relates to a table, which has primary and foreign keys?

I have a View-A (all 3 fields are Foreign Keys) and that view gets 2 fields from a View-B. The View-B gets its fields from a table-C. table-C has primary key and foreign key.

So when i access View-A with my django model, how do i treat those fields? I know they are foreign keys, but any kind of filter results in a empty Queryset.
if i use something like

```
myview = viewA.objects.using(db).all()  # getting all the data
myview2= viewA.objects.using(db).all()[:5] # getting 5 objects
```

.

```
class viewA(models.Model):
class Meta:
    db_table = "viewA"

x = models.ForeignKey(x, primary_key=True)
y = models.ForeignKey(y)
z = models.ForeignKey(z)
```

The problem is that i can not filter!

```
response=viewA.objects.using(db).filter(y_id=1)  ERROR:= FieldError
```

Behind all those FK, there are integer/bigint fields.

Edit:
Since this are INNER JOINS i would like to access not only the fields from ViewA, but also from ViewB. x,y,z are from type ViewB. Maybe use **select_related()**?

So any clues if Django or postgres lose information about keys in views which relate to other views?

Comment: Are you using more than one database?

Comment: Also, did you try: response=viewA.objects.using(db).filter(y=1) ?

Comment: it is 1 database. and (y=1) got me a record back :D, but if i want to access another field with like y__name i get again an empty Queryset back.The Problem is too, that kinda all Foreign/Primary Keys have a _id in their name.

Comment: Since it's one db, you don't need to use .using(db), unless there is some other reason for it (but generally, it's when you have more than one DB). Also, i'll ammend my answer some below to incorporate what you said here

Comment: ok,hmm but the problem with y=1 is, that i access the viewA with the field y. I would like to access the fields of the viewB, which in this specific case would be the Views, which are represented through x, y or z. in the view y(aka ViewB) i would like to access a field name. That is not working

Comment: see my edits below (below edits). I understand what you are looking for, you just need to drill down into the foreignkey object by using the double underscore and that your criteria isn't matching anything in the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my two comments; however, to answer your specific "query".

If you go to the docs, and see this paragraph:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#database-representation

You will note that foreign keys, by default, have the _id appended to their names. Now, there are occasions in which you need to access the column name directly and it's a good idea to be aware of the column as a "bigger picture" sort of thing, but at as far as Model API is concerned, you should, when doing something against a foreign key, use the attribute name given in the model instance.

Edit from your comment:

If you want to drill down and filter against some field in the foreignkey object, you just do y__fieldname = somevalue

Note that fieldname must be in the y object.

If you are getting back and empty queryset, this is because nothing in that column matched the value you gave it.

To test this, create a queryset directly on the "y" object and then try to do y.objects.fitler(fieldname=somevalue)

if you still get back and empty queryset, you know that value doesn't exist. Furthermore, you can look into the database and try a raw query in pgadminIII if you have that set up.

Comment: thx for your work! if i use **y.objects.fitler(fieldname=somevalue)** i get what i expect. But when i use it on the ViewA and want to drill down to compare fields in viewB(y), the QuerySet is empty

Comment: Are you certain that that specific line is saved to ViewA? Otherwise, your query will still return nothing